# Sublime Text - Extend HTML Syntax Inside New "HTML (Custom)" Syntax

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, 4d-database

### Background

I am working with a language called [Webclerk](http://www.jpods.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=WebClerk.HTMLCommands), which uses custom tags to query a [4D database](http://www.4d.com/). It works similarly to PHP. Instead of a `.php` file which is processed into HTML, this uses a '.wc' file which is processed into HTML.

Instead of something like:  `<?php echo $variable; ?>`, it would look like `_jit_ echo $variable; jj`

`<?php` = `_jit_`, `?>` = `jj`.

In Sublime Text, when PHP is selected as the Syntax, PHP is highlighted a different block color, on top of the HTML highlighting. I'd like to do the same thing for these special tags.

I really don't care about highlighting text inside the brackets. I would be completely satisfied with just having a highlight/background color starting and stopping with the tags.

### What I've Done

I have installed Package Manager, and Package Resource Viewer, then extracted the PHP and the HTML packages to examine them. I've been going through tutorials as well. I'm running into a problem with the two different types of syntax highlighting (.tmLanguage vs .sublime-syntax). There is a lot of info on the first way, and very little on the second. I feel like just starting and stopping highlighting based on two tags can't be that difficult.

---

When I opened the HTML package, I get:

```
Comments.tmPreferences
HTML.sublime-syntax
Miscellaneous.tmPreferences
Symbol List - ID.tmPreferences
encode_html_entities.py
html.sublime-snippet
html_completions.py
```

Almost none of these are mentioned in tutorials. I tried just changing the names of HTML to Webclerk, and I did manage to get a new Syntax in the list. But when I edited tags, nothing changed in what was highlighted.

## Question

I'm wondering if I can get some pointers on where to start, on what these files mean, and potentially any examples where people have extended HTML before.

Answer (score 1):

basically you're trying to define a custom scope with a start & end regexp selectors
that is documented here:
http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#begin-end-rules

I have also ran into this intresting discussion on the sublime text board from somebody trying to do exactcly what you're trying to do http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6207
There is some helpful information and tips in it.

I would start in the `HTML.sublime-package` package inside `HTML.tmLanauage` package on line 598 (in my setup) there is a definition for php start & end tags, it looks like a regex that recognizes the tags and highlights them

BTW `.sublime-package` are just zip files, you can rename them and extract.
then put the extracted folder inside `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages` to run it

Comment: I've been looking at those links. Still haven't gotten it working fully, but I'm going to award you the bounty so that it doesn't disappear.

Comment: There are several issues with this answer: first, the OP is using a [dev build](https://sublimetext.com/3dev) of ST3, meaning all the default `.tmLanguage` files have been replaced with the new YAML-based `.sublime-syntax` files. Second, all the business about zip files and `HTML.sublime-package` are completely unnecessary - OP is already using PackageResourceViewer, which does all of that seamlessly. Finally, you don't put extracted packages in `Installed Packages`, they go in `Packages`, otherwise they won't override the zipped version.